# How a variables retrieve and stores data

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I working on a development on Oracle Application Express and I am new to this application.

I have a stored procedure that takes a variable from the Oracle APEX application when executed. A button triggers this action.

My PL/SQL code on Oracle APEX takes the file name I uploaded as parameter. See below code.

```
BEGIN
CLOSE_PO(:P_FILE_NAME );
END;
```

The file name is stored in a temporary table on the database.

Can anyone briefly explain how the variable in the PL/SQL code is able to retrieve the filename in the table?

Comment: A bit more info: how did you upload the file? What is this "temporary" table you're talking about?

Comment: Please, remove tags "apex-code" & "apex", if you read descriptions you find they are not related to Oracle Apex

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your question but I try to help.

In APEX you can upload files by creating in a region a **File Browse** item that manage the corresponding dialog and show the filename you select for uploading.

For the complete list of steps and items to create I use  [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#CIHBFCDH) .

The file name is stored in the page item value (e.g. :P1_FILE_BROWSE).
The file is stored in the APEX table **APEX_APPLICATION_FILES** and it is possible to query it like

```
SELECT * 
FROM APEX_APPLICATION_FILES 
WHERE FIELNAME = :P1_FILE_BROWSE
```

In the PL\SQL for an action you can query the table and retrieve the variables you need to pass to stored procedure as parameters.